# Keras - If I want to take three or more inputs of varying data sizes and types, is this model architecture correct?

Tags: python, keras

I'm wanting to pass in three differently formatted inputs (ex, one is a number, one is a one hot encoded array, and the other is an embedding problem) into my Keras functional model and get a number out (regression problem). I've only worked with sequential models in the past, so I'm having trouble understanding how this works.

Here's my current model architecture (`input_a` is one hot, `input_b` is a number from 0 to 1, and `input_c` is another one hot, different size):

[image]

However, I'm not exactly sure if this is the 'correct' way my model should be formatted for my intention. Because when I change my third input out so that it's an embedding input, Keras complains that the input shape is incorrect. That dataset should be an array of integers, so I set the `input_size` to 1, but the embedding layer is saying it's getting an array of 129 size. Which is the length of my dense layer above it, so I think it's receiving the dense's output and not my input.

Here's my model formatted the same, but with embedding (it's failing):

```
input_a = Input(shape=genres.shape[1:], name='input_a')

x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_a)
output_a = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

input_b = Input(shape=(1,), name='input_b')
x = keras.layers.concatenate([output_a, input_b])

x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
output_b = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

input_c = Input(shape=(1,), name='input_c')
x = keras.layers.concatenate([output_b, input_c])

x = Embedding(max(directors) + 1, 16, input_length=1)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

output_c = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b, input_c], outputs=output_c)
```

But I get `"input_length" is 1, but received input has shape (None, 129)`

How can I make `input_c` receive the actual third input and not the output from the above layers?

Comment: You are passing the output of concatenation to embedding layer, which is not correct. Is the `input_c` representing the directors? If so, then just pass it directly to the embedding layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input_c = Input(shape=(10,))
x = Embedding(1024, 16, input_length=10)(input_c)
output_c = Flatten()(x)

input_a = Input(shape=(10,))
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_a)
output_a = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

input_b = Input(shape=(1,))
x = concatenate([output_a, input_b])
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
output_b = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

x = concatenate([output_b, output_c], axis=1)
output_c = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model([input_a, input_b, input_c], output_c)
model.predict([np.random.randn(1000,10), 
               np.random.randn(1000,1), 
               np.random.randint(0,1023,size=(1000,10))])
```

Embedding layers takes in as input the indices to words, so do not concatenate it with the other inputs. Rather pass input_c to embedding layers and then concatenate the flattened word embeddings with others.

Comment: Thanks so much! Looks really good. I figured out something similar to this that works now, so I'll just have to do some comparing on the model architecture and see which is best.